# Are there problems with UEFI when single-booting Ubuntu?

Tags: uefi

As some of you may know, I recently (and unsuccessfully!) tried to dual-boot Ubuntu with Microsoft Windows 8.1 on a Sony VAIO Tap 20... However it was a *nightmare* with problem after problem and being that only the kids use that particular computer, I went back to a Windows 8.1-only setup.

Now with my *personal* computer however, I dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 fine (spending most of my time in the former)... However it is a *much* older laptop that is on its last legs and *eventually* I will need to replace it, almost certainly with a UEFI-based computer (seeing as that is what is replacing the BIOS in *all* computers over the next few years).

--

Now that the back-story is out of the way, I have a really, *really* easy question (well, at least I *think* it is)...

--

If I single-boot a future computer with Ubuntu, do *all* of the UEFI issues simply "go away"? Or will this vary from manufacturer to manufacturer (as is the case with dual-booting)?

I've learnt quite a bit about UEFI over the last few weeks and as I understand it, a *lot* of the booting problems come down to Windows 8.1 modifying the boot sequence when dual-booting... Effectively undoing some or all of the changes a Ubuntu may have made.

But if Windows 8.1 has been removed (along with all of its partitions, including the "recovery" partitions), there should be no difference to single-booting a BIOS-based computer with Ubuntu, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies from one computer to another. Some have badly broken EFIs that will only boot the Windows boot loader, for instance. (To be more precise, they'll only boot a file called `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`, or sometimes only one with the name that Microsoft gives their boot loader ["Windows Boot Manager" or something like that, IIRC].) Such a problem can often be worked around by renaming GRUB, rEFInd, or whatever you use, but that's an *ugly* solution! Others have EFIs that work the way they're supposed to work, in which case an Ubuntu-only installation -- or even a Windows/Ubuntu dual-boot -- should go fairly smoothly. The biggest caveat in such cases is that you understand enough about it to not make any dire mistakes. To that end, I strongly recommend that you read the following three pages:

- [My page on EFI booting on Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)
- [Adam Williamson's page on EFI booting](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)
- [The Ubuntu community wiki on the subject](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Any one of those will help immensely, and reading the other two will help fill in the gaps.

Based on the sorts of comments and problems I've seen on-line, I'd say that, in addition to buggy EFIs, the biggest problem is that users bring BIOS assumptions to the EFI world. That's why I always squirm a bit when I see somebody refer to a new computer's "BIOS." It doesn't have a BIOS; it's got an EFI, and the fact that the person is referring to it as a BIOS means they're loading up their mental model with BIOS assumptions that *do not apply* to EFIs.

As to your specific issue, following links, I see you had problems with a Sony VIAO machine. Those problems were likely caused, at least in part, by Sony-specific bugs. Therefore, I recommend you buy another brand of computer. FWIW, I recently bought a Lenovo IdeaPad U530, and its firmware isn't doing anything flaky. It dual-boots between Linux and Windows just fine, although I think I've booted Windows all of once in two months since getting Ubuntu installed. OTOH, I'm the maintainer of rEFInd (which of course I use on this system), so my knowledge of how to set this up is well above average; somebody else might have a much harder time with this exact same computer. ASUS has also been ahead of the game on EFI adoption, although I can't comment on any specific ASUS computer.